# Subtraction of Data in two DataTables

Tags: c#, sql, linq, data-binding, datatable

I have two DataTables which are populated from a database. These two DataGrids have the same schema but different data in the `Qty` column. I want to subtract the value of 2nd DataTable's `QTY` column from the first and then want to store it into a third DataTable.

Below is my code for 1st DataTable.

```
DataTable newDt1 = dt_1.AsEnumerable()
                       .GroupBy(r => r.Field<int>("batch_num"))
                       .Select(g =>
                                   {
                                        var row = dt_1.NewRow();
                                        row["batch_num"] = g.Key;
                                        row["qty"] = g.Sum(r => Convert.ToInt32(r.Field<int>("qty")));
                                        return row;
                                   })
                       .CopyToDataTable();
```

2nd DataTable has same code as above just it is being updated with new values.

Comment: You needn't ask for permission here, just go ahead. If you have a question, then post it.

Comment: I have not asked for any type of permissions.

Comment: I have posted my question, not asked for permission

Comment: relation between two data table on `batch_num` ?

Comment: Batch num is unique and it is retrived from database. It should be like this where batch number in both datatable matches. Then subtract there QTY Column and store BATCH_NUM and QTY in third dataTable,

Comment: please help to resolve it.

Comment: @Niazi as i dont have compiler right now, so i had tried something similar online.. here https://dotnetfiddle.net/u33ml3 go and try it out. and let me know if it works for you or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to create your scenario in a console application. Following code will help you to develop your solution.

```
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
dt1.Columns.Add("BatchNo");
dt1.Columns.Add("Qty");

DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
dt2.Columns.Add("BatchNo");
dt2.Columns.Add("Qty");

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    dt1.Rows.Add(i + 1, i + 2);
    dt2.Rows.Add(i + 1, i + 3);
}

var result = dt1.AsEnumerable()
.Join(dt2.AsEnumerable(), d1 => d1["BatchNo"], d2 => d2["BatchNo"], (d1, d2) => new { D1 = d1, D2 = d2 })
.Select(r => new 
{
    BatchNo = Convert.ToInt32( r.D1["BatchNo"] ),
    QtyDifference = Convert.ToInt32(r.D2["Qty"]) - Convert.ToInt32(r.D1["Qty"])
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dear.

Comment: @Niazi Kindly upvote or mark as an answer if it is useful so other can refer it in case of same question. Thanks!

Comment: now i am trying to display this var result into the DataGrid by doing this dataGrid2.ItemsSource = result.DefaultView; 
but it is giving me this error that it does not contain definition for DefaultView.

Comment: I think, Result is not the DataView. So you need to prepare a datatable or dataview to display it. This is very basic sample I created.